# Instance method 'contains' requires that 'UITextField' conform to 'StringProtocol'

Tags: arrays, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a tableview that displays a sourceArray with a Name and Category properties.  I want to filter the Category property of the sourceArray based on the users input from a UIAlertController but getting the error "Instance method 'contains' requires that 'UITextField' conform to 'StringProtocol'". Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
var sourceArray = [(Name: String, Category: String, Picture1: UIImage, Picture2: UIImage, Picture3: UIImage, Description: String)]()

@IBAction func filterButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var textField = UITextField()
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Category", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Filter", style: .default) { (action) in
        print(textField)
        let filtered = sourceArray.filter({$0.Category.contains(textField)})
        self.filteredArray = filteredArray.isEmpty ? sourceArray : filtered
        self.tableview.reloadData()

    }
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Biceps, Chest, Shoulders, etc."
        textField = alertTextField
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```

Comment: what is `sourceArray`?

Comment: sourceArray is the array that I am using to populate the tableView.  It contains exercise names and their category.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You create a new, not-connected-with-anything UITextField, and then try to see if your sourceArray contains that text field object?

Comment: Doesn't the code create the textField and create an UIAlertAction to filter for the textField from the sourceArray?  This is how I understand it to be written.

Comment: It is very likely that my logic is not working here.  I am trying to filter the sourceArray based on the content entered in the textField. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand what "... create the textField and create an UIAlertAction to filter for the textField from the sourceArray" means. The text field you create isn't attached to anything. And why would your sourceArray contain a text field in its Category property?

Comment: The sourceArray:      var sourceArray = [(Name: String, Category: String, Picture1: UIImage, Picture2: UIImage, Picture3: UIImage, Description: String)]()

Comment: Are you trying to create an alert that collects a string, and when the user clicks a filter button on the alert, filters your table view data source to only include items that contain the user-entered string?

Comment: Edit your original question to provide the definition of `sourceArray`. Those reading the question should not have to slog through tons of "twenty questions" comments to understand your app.

Comment: And your code still makes no sense. Why would a tuple that consists of strings and images contain a UITextField?

Comment: Sorry for the rudimentary explanation but I am nothing more than a novice programmer.  I thought a textField is a String and with that I could filter the sourceArray's Category (String) based on that textField.  My apologies!  I'll look somewhere else to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This issue I was having is that textField was not being recognized as a String.  So I added a constant text as a String and assigned the textField.text to it like so.

```
@IBAction func filterButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var textField = UITextField()
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Category", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Filter", style: .default) { (action) in
        
        let text: String = textField.text!
        let filtered = self.sourceArray.filter({$0.Category.contains(text)})
        self.filteredArray = self.filteredArray.isEmpty ? self.sourceArray : filtered
        self.tableview.reloadData()

    }
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Biceps, Chest, Shoulders, etc."
        textField = alertTextField
    }
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
```